# Call to a member function tournaments() on null LARAVEL 8

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller, laravel-blade

Hi in my controller i have in store underline on tournaments(), i dont know why because i have define fillable in my Tournament model and connect user and tournaments, belongsTo and hasMany.

Do you see my mistake?

Thanks four yours advices.

> Controller.php

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{

    $tournament = Auth::user()->tournaments()->create($request->all());
    $route = 'http://localhost:8000/turnaj/' . $tournament->slug;
    return redirect()->route($route);
}
```

> Tournament.php

```
    protected $table = "tournaments";

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'city',
    'street',
    'game_room',
    'e-mail',
    'phone',
    'text',
    'registration_link',
    'time_registration_at',
    'date_registration_at',
    'time_starter_at',
    'date_starter_at',
    'slug',
    'region_id',
    'user_id',
];
```

> User.php

```
protected $table = "users";

public function tournaments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tournament::class);
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you, but error report is in TITLE. I have problem with middleware.

Comment: Ok, I remove my comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the logged user is necessary for the store operation, you should protect the store route by using [auth](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#protecting-routes) middleware, for example:

```
Route::post('/tournaments', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may access this route...
})->middleware('auth');
```

now you guarantee that  `Auth::user()` will get the current logged user

Comment: Thanks for your help yesterday i logged in but today a forgot and it was problem, i add middleware. How you write redirect for save post?

Comment: simply redirect to the route: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirects